# check if there is a "Complete" each week, if not change one weekly cell to "Incomplete" and the rest "Not Applicable"

Tags: excel, vba

I feel like I'm going down a rabbit hole! I keep unsuccessfully trying different ways to check if a task is done any day of each week of the month.

Date cells are in column "D" and I want to see if a task in column "Y" was completed during the week. If there is a "Complete" in the week, go to the next week. If no "Complete" (could be blank or "Not Applicable") change Friday to "Incomplete". The remaining days are "Not Applicable".

Here is my most recent attempt. In this I didnt try to specifically get Friday to be "Incomplete". Nothing happens. Blanks remain blank and there are "Not Applicable's" all week. Thank you!

```
Sub onceaweek()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim currentDate As Date
Dim currentWeek As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim completeFound As Boolean
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("rawday")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    
    currentDate = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
    currentWeek = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(currentDate, vbMonday)

    Set rng = ws.Range("Y" & i & ":Y" & WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(currentDate, 6), ws.Columns(4), 1))

    completeFound = False
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "Complete" Then
            completeFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
    If Not completeFound Then
        ws.Cells(i, 25).Value = "Incomplete"
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, rng.Columns.Count - 1).Value = "Not Applicable"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you're doing something quite complicated, for which formulas might be better suited. What do your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

- `rng` is a range which includes one / more cells in Col Y. that is, n Rows x 1 Col . `rng.Columns.Count - 1` will be zero. That's the reason why nothing is changed after running the code.
- More more thing, `rng` should be offset by a row instead of a column.

```vb
rng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, rng.Columns.Count - 1).Value = "Not Applicable"
```

*Change:*

- Update `rng` with `Not Applicable`, then update the cell (Friday) with `Incomplete`

```vb
        If Not completeFound Then
            Dim iWKDay As Long
            iWKDay = WorksheetFunction.Weekday(currentDate, 11)
            rng.Value = "Not Applicable"
            ws.Cells(i + (5 - iWKDay), 25).Value = "Incomplete"
        End If
```